# How to check if IIS closed the connection after sending file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a web application where I'm using OWIN to send files to the client by implementing `Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems.IFileInfo`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems;

public class CmsFileInfo : IFileInfo
{
    private readonly FileInfo _fileInfo;
    private readonly string _physicalPath;

    public CmsFileInfo(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        _fileInfo = fileInfo;
        _physicalPath = fileInfo.FullName;
        Name = fileInfo.Name;
        LastModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc;
    }

    public Stream CreateReadStream()
    {
        return new FileStream(
            _physicalPath,
            FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read,
            FileShare.Read,
            1024 * 64,
            FileOptions.SequentialScan);
    }

    public long Length
    {
        get { return _fileInfo.Length; }
    }

    public string PhysicalPath { get { return null; } }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; private set; }
    public bool IsDirectory { get { return false; } }
}
```

For me, it seems that is is working fine. But then we had some problems with iTunes. An apple supporter gave me the following answer:

> It seems when we request your image, your server isn't closing the connection. Consider hosting your image on a different and seeing if that resolves the issue.

We moved the podcast image to azure and I'm now sending a 302 redirect. This solved our problem with iTunes.

But: How can I close the connection? How can I test if the server closed the connection? What's wrong with my IFileInfo implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect whether or not the underlying TCP connection was closed.